# Emacs slows to a crawl when Chrome is running

Tags: performance, x11

Really bizarre issue here; I suspect it's X-related. This may be better suited to the Linux/Unix SE, but I figured there might be more domain-specific expertise here.

Often (but not 100% of the time), if I run Emacs and Chromium (or google-chrome, I'm on Ubuntu) at the same time, then UI updates on Emacs take *ages* to show. As in, I'll try to scroll around the package menu and it will take 45 seconds to render a few dozen lines worth of scrolling. It seems to go both ways: I'm updating 31 packages in the background as I type this and there's a few seconds of lag between every character I type and the on-screen rendering.

This issue occurs with both `emacsclient`s and stand-alone Emacs sessions. I have 6 cores and I see that only one of them is being used at the moment, which I think must be the cause of the issue. I 'm only at 60% memory usage with almost no swap space being used, so it's not a question of the system being over-taxed.

It looks like the lag spikes correlate with CPU-intensive actions in Emacs. It's almost as if chromium and Emacs have decided to run on the same core and compete for cycles, but I can't imagine why.

I'm on the latest Ubuntu release, via Xubuntu, and I use XMonad as my window manager. I've never had any other pair of programs have this kind of issue. Firefox doesn't cause this problem, I only discovered it recently after switching to Chrome. What's going on here?

Comment: Can you reproduce it when you run Emacs without your init file? (`emacs -Q`) What about if you start up Chrome with a different profile instead?

Comment: @db48x: Yes, the behavior is the same in both of those circumstances (`emacs -Q` and `chromium-browser --temp-profile`). Closing one or the other fixes the problem.

Comment: Also, perhaps unsurprisingly, the problem isn't present if I run it via `emacs -nw`.

Comment: That is curious. I guess you could try profiling one or the other to find out what's going on.

Comment: Same problem here, but just noticed that the spotify-client also causes this.

Comment: @tristan Wow, someone else with this problem! I thought I was the only one. Are you on Linux? Do you have any strange graphics-related settings? I'd like to file some kind of a bug somewhere on this but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: @tristan In particular, do you use `fglrx`?

Comment: @PatrickCollins Yep, using fglrx. At some stage I had success getting it run faster by running Xnest, and emacs or chrome through that. Not working at the moment.

Comment: Can you open htop during one of these lags to find out what processes are actually using the CPU? It does indeed sound like a problem with X, so Emacs and Chrome may not be the source of the problem. In my case, xorg was using 100% of my CPU, and went back to normal after I stopped using xcompmgr.

Comment: @Tyler I've switched from an ATI graphics card to an NVidia one (temporarily dropping 2 of my 3 monitors until I can get the right adapters), switched from `fglrx` to the proprietary NVidia drivers, and I can no longer reproduce the issue. I don't know if that's a coincidence or not, I will circle back to this when I have my other monitors reconnected. My current suspicion is that it's an `fglrx` issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try running "xcompmgr -n &". (See https://michaelheap.com/google-chrome-stealing-focus-repainting-in-xmonad/)

This finally fixed emacs for me, but, ironically, it has slowed google-chrome down in the current session I am in.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer, but it kind of is. I just don't have rep to comment other wise I would.

This happens to me as well, except I do not use xmonad, I use i3wm, but it goes away if I have the chromium window tiled with another window on the same screen. I also experience this with steam/steam games.

Running htop reveals no process utilizing large amounts of CPU. I speculate that the problem is in an thread that typically "waits" synchronously rather than asynchronously somewhere in Emacs.

Answer (score -1):

use firefox instead. chrome is buggy. besides, keysnail is a great firefox ONLY addon to convert firefox to emacs